# swift Firebase remove observer

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I noticed that liked or not liked prints are fired as many times as I opened the view controller, so I added a remove observer (i tried all listed) in viewDidDisappear but it continues to fire multiple times, can someone help me?

This is my code:

```swift
 private var databaseHandle: FIRDatabaseHandle!
 var ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
 var isLiked: Bool = false
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

isLiked = false

databaseHandle = ref.child("favperuser").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).observe( .value, with:{(snap) in

            if snap.hasChild(self.detailId){

                print("is liked")
                self.isLiked = true
                 self.likeButton.setTitle("Unlike", for: .normal)

                self.likeButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "star-")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
                self.likeButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "star-")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .highlighted)

            }else{

                print("not liked")
                self.isLiked = false
                self.likeButton.setTitle("Like!", for: .normal)

                self.likeButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "star+")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
                self.likeButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "star+")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .highlighted)

            }


          })
        self.isLiked = false

}


      @IBAction func likePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {


        if self.isLiked == false {

            ref.child("favperuser").child( FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).updateChildValues([detailId: true])


        } else {


            ref.child("favperuser").child( FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).child(detailShellId).removeValue { (error, ref) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("error \(error)")
                }
            }



        }

    }



    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

    ref.removeObserver(withHandle: databaseHandle)

    ref.child("favperuser").removeObserver(withHandle: databaseHandle)
    ref.child("favperuser").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).removeObserver(withHandle: databaseHandle)
}
```

Comment: `viewDidDisappear` actually called?

Comment: yes with a close function, anyway i also putted the remover inside of the close function and nothing changed

Comment: Are you sure you aren't calling `observe` multiple times per VC presentation? This would explain why you can't seem to remove *all* observers (and is actually just removing the last one registered).

Comment: I' tried to leave only 
ref.child("favperuser").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).removeObserver(withHandle: databaseHandle)
in the wiewDisapper function and now works

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this link:-

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#detach_listeners

Also after removing all the references by handler just removeAllObservers for that ref in case any observer left and it might continue sync, and it should be removed mostly after receiving the snapshot from firebase as I was also facing the same issue doing that resolved my issue.